# Startup rsync backup don't work anymore

Tags: mount, rsync

looks like this don´t work anymore...

```
mount | awk '{if ($3 == "/media/NAS") { exit 0}} ENDFILE {exit -1}' && rsync -r -t -v --progress --delete -s /media/NAS /home/alebal/Desktop/NAS_BCK
```

Should check if the directory is mounted and then backup... but... no...

Why?

(Grsync works good)

Comment: You have to tell us what you saw that led you to believe it's not functioning. Update your question with the actual output.

Comment: I add a new file and i don´t find it in the backup folder...

Comment: Separate the first part of your command from the second. Did the mount check pass? Replace "rsync ..." with "echo rsync ..." and enter your command at the terminal and confirm that the mount check passes and rsync runs. Once that works, then just run rsync, but this time change `/media/NAS` to a specific test subdirectory 
 (like `/media/NAS/test`, say) that you just populate with a couple test files.